# Cannot create a directed graph using from_pandas_dataframe from networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, network-analysis

I'm learning networkx library and use twitter retweet directed graph data. 
I first read the datasets into pandas df (columns are 'from','to','weight') and wanted to put a first 300 rows(retweet) into a graph using below code:

```
tw_small = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(edges_df[:300],source='from',
                                   target='to',edge_attr=True)
```

I thought that it correctly created a graph but when I run `tw_small.is_directed()`, it says `False`(undirected graph) and I drew a graph using `nx.draw()` but it doesn't show the direction either.

Could someone help me find a correct way to make a directed graph?

Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Add the optional keyword argument create_using=nx.DiGraph(),

```
tw_small = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(edges_df[:300],source='from',
                                   target='to',edge_attr=True,
                                   create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

Comment: Thank you. The syntax for the create_using agrument was not clearly explained in the documentation.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but `from_pandas_datafarme` has been deprecated, how would you do it with more current tools?

Comment: @OfekGlick, not sure if you're still looking for this, but you would use `from_pandas_edgelist`, so it would be `G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges_df, source='from', target='to', edge_attr=True, create_using=nx.DiGraph())` (which is what the other solution below by Hamdi Tarek is saying).

Answer (score 12):

Instead of a dataframe you can write edgelist, it works for me, it shows me an error when I used `from_pandas_dataframe : "AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_pandas_dataframe`"

#### Solution :

```
Graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,source='source',target='destination', edge_attr=None, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

You can test if your graph is directed or not using: `nx.is_directed(Graph)`. You will get True.